# Assign a key to array and group it by name and email in one array

Tags: php, arrays

Hi all I'm novice in PHP and I do not know if somebody can help me to how to solve this:

I have an array that look's like this:

```
array (size=6)
  0 => 'alexg'
  1 => 'benny'
  2 => 'shahar'
  3 => 'alexag@website.com'
  4 => 'ben_r@website.com'
  5 => 'shah_iar@website.com'
```

How do I make it to look like this (assign a key and group it by name and email in one array):

```
array (size=3)
  array (size=2)
    'USERLOGIN' => 'alexg'
    'EMAIL' => 'alexag@website.com'
  array (size=2)
    'USERLOGIN' => 'benny'
    'EMAIL' => 'ben_r@website.com'
  array (size=2)
    'USERLOGIN' => 'shahar'
    'EMAIL' => 'shah_iar@website.com'
```

Until now i achive this:

```
array (size=6)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'USERLOGIN' => string 'benny'
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'USERLOGIN' => string 'alexg'
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      'USERLOGIN' => string 'shahar'
  3 => 
    array (size=1)
      'EMAIL' => string 'bennyr@website.com'
  4 => 
    array (size=1)
      'EMAIL' => string 'alexg@website.com'
  5 => 
    array (size=1)
      'EMAIL' => string 'shahar@website.com'
```

Thank you in advance and I hope somebody could help me.

Comment: How you determine which email will go with which name? Users can use a random name for the email.

Comment: This is my question also.. I need to group it by name and email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your array will always be 1st half logins and 2nd half emails :

```
$array = ['alexg', 'benny', 'shahar', 'alexag@website.com', 'ben_r@website.com', 'shah_iar@website.com'];

$len = count($array);
$half = $len/2;
  
$usernames = array_slice($array, 0, $half);
$emails = array_slice($array, $half, $len);
$allUsers = [];
    
foreach($usernames as $username) {
    $myUser['USERLOGIN'] = $username;
    array_push($allUsers, $myUser);
}
foreach($emails as $key=>$email) {
    $allUsers[$key]['EMAIL'] = $email;
}

var_dump($allUsers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to just create the array? You can do it like this:

```php
$variableName = [
    [
        'USERLOGIN' => 'alexg',
        'EMAIL' => 'alexag@website.com',
    ],
    [
        'USERLOGIN' => 'benny',
        'EMAIL' => 'ben_r@website.com',
    ],
    [
        'USERLOGIN' => 'shahar',
        'EMAIL' => 'shah_iar@website.com',
    ],
];
```

Comment: How do i create the array from initial array? This are dynamic data that came from database comma separated and i use explode and then array_merge ($users=explode(',',$window['users']); $emails = explode(',', $window['emails']);)